# TinyMCE with React.js is displaying html tags in frontend

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, tinymce

I am trying to implement [TinyMCE](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react) with React.js along with DRF in backend.

The tinymce Editor is saving data along with html elements in DB. Main issue i am facing here when I try 
to display data in frontend, it displays html tags too.(also, in browser inspect elements it
is showing as a single string, here I have attached a screenshot)

How do I display data in proper html format as intended to do without displaying those html tags in frontend?

[image]

Here is settings for tinymce

```
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';


handleEditorChange = (e) => {

    this.setState({
      content: e.target.getContent({ format: 'html' })

   })

}
<Editor
   apiKey="t80f2hbf54gftyp5lr9wre6ud85z5o12gf54kjaywq10bk1gue"

   init={{
         selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: ['advlist autolink autosave lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor 
            pagebreak','searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
           'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table  directionality','emoticons template paste  
            textpattern imagetools codesample toc help'],
        toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright 
            alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
       toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample help',
         image_advtab: true,
         file_browser_callback_types: 'image',
          valid_elements: '*[*]',
         branding: false,
         height: 400,
         contextmenu: 'formats | link image',
         forced_root_block: false,

     }}

      name='content'
       onChange={this.handleEditorChange}

/>
```

Comment: How are you actually attempting to render the HTML in question on the page? All content in TinyMCE is HTML, and so this looks more like an issue in getting React to render the HTML created in TinyMCE. Are you using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React or some similar process?

Comment: No, I am not using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. If i understood correctly your first question, I am simply saving data to DB without any modification, from their i am rendering contents in frontend like {blog.content} with api request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React will not render a string of HTML on its own. From their [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in
>   the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because
>   it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting
>   (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have
>   to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html
>   key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

So in this case, something like:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div class="blog_content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={blog.content} />;
}
```

..should render the HTML content created in TinyMCE.

Comment: Thank you @Tiny. It helps :)

Comment: Just be aware that rendering user input directly with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` can introduce XSS vulnerability. Best practice is to put some sanitization based on whitelisting certain tags on backend both before storing user input and before rendering it.